# Issues installing Numexpr ( and PyTables as a result)

Tags: python

I'm running into a problem installing numexpr in order to install PyTables so I can deal with massive data sets.

Build Details:
Windows 7 Pro 64-Bit, Python 2.7, numexpr 2.01, numpy v1.6.1, scipy v0.10.1

Here's what's happening:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import numexpr as ne

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numexpr\__init__.py", line 38, in <
      from numexpr.expressions import E
 File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numexpr\expressions.py", line 31, i
      from numexpr import interpreter
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

It also gives that error when I just try from numexpr.expressions import E.

My path includes:

c:\python27\;c:\python27\scripts\;c:\python27\lib\site-packages\

Comment: I see you accepted Chrismit's answer, but I don't see what part of his answer solved your problem.  Could you share what you did to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that can be happening.  This should narrow it down

1) Check c:\python27\DLLs for the dll it's trying to import.

2) See what part of the procedure is throwing the error.  Use ipython to import numexpr, then import interpreter to see if its an import within those imports that's causing the error

3) this will result in probably 2 things:

a) You don't have the DLL it's looking for and this is resolved by installing that package

b) The DLL being imported is there, but a dependency of that DLL isn't.  Use dependency walker, load the DLL and see what's missing

Comment: How do you do #1?  I have this same exact problem and I don't see anything in the error which would tell me what dll might be missing.  I assume I need to enable additional logging to find out?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered installing [Python(x,y)](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/)?

Python 2.7, numexpr, numpy, scipy, and PyTables are all included in a single installer, as well as [lots of other stuff](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/StandardPlugins) that you may find useful for your data analysis.  It should allow you to skip over the installation troubles you're having with the individual packages.